# facebook open graph have to reload page to post to timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Very confused, but my open graph works.  The only problem is I have to hit refresh a few times for it to actually post to timeline.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You should consider giving more info or code you tried. The question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You should add the javascript timeout function to call facebook a few seconds after the page has loaded. E.g.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //  publish action to facebook
            FB.api( '/me/news.reads', 'post', { article : 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your_article/' } );
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
}, 2000 );
```

This will allow enough time for Facebook SDK to load and initialise, before posting your action off to facebook.